# Mongodb Couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I'm getting the following error:
whenever i am running
`mongo`
on ubuntu

````
MongoDB shell version v4.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1```

[![screenshot of error][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZAEl.png
````

Comment: It means what it said: the server refused to accept your connection.

Comment: Question is not clear . Could you please elaborate more on it with some screen-shot

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZAEl.png added screenshot

Comment: looks like your mongo service is not running if you installed using brew use it to start the service with something like this `brew services start mongodb-community`
name of the service may differ based on your version

Comment: I am using ubuntu and have not used brew installation

Comment: @prabalgupta I guess you have to start the server using the command ```mongod```. then in new terminal try ```mongo```. I guess it will work,

Comment: the server generated these startup warnings when booting: 
        2021-06-17T12:30:10.183+05:30: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
        2021-06-17T12:30:11.711+05:30: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
        2021-06-17T12:30:11.711+05:30: Soft rlimits too low
        2021-06-17T12:30:11.711+05:30:         currentValue: 1024
        2021-06-17T12:30:11.711+05:30:         recommendedMinimum: 64000